# Android - getTabHost() is undefined

Tags: java, android

I started learning Java and how to program for Android last night :)

So far I'm on this tutorial: developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Clearly these tutorials have been designed for people that already have experience with Java.

Despite the tutorial lacking all the required steps (for an absolute beginner with Java) and even having a typo, it seems I've figured everything out (which I'm really proud of :p). Except I cannot figure out how to fix `TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();` which apparently is undefined.

I have one other error shown in the linked image below, but I don't see why.

Here is the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/annOx.png).

Thanks, Gareth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just missed step 5 of the tutorial.

The other error is due to the capital T on TabHost. You want: `tabHost.addTab(spec);`

Java is case sensitive, so it makes a difference (calling a non-exsistant static method of the TabHost class vs. calling an instance method on the object referenced by the tabHost variable).

Comment: Thank you! You fixed the 'tabHost.addTab(spec);' issue.

Now finally being able to test my app, and it crashes.

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I am tremendously happy, thank you and AaronM so much!

Comment: its not working in my fragment...it shows..The method getTabHost() is undefined for the type HomeFragment

Answer (score 24):

getTabHost() is a method of TabActivity not Activity. You'll need to extend that instead of Activity for the method to be defined in your object.

Comment: Thank you! I had 'extends Activity {' instead of 'extends TabActivity {'

Answer (score 0):

Now that [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) is deprecated in API level 13, it is recommended to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) instead. Still possible, however, to use a support library for compatibility back to DONUT.